# Why text on SWC doesn't show up when imported from FlashDevelop?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flashdevelop, swc

I created many SWCs with graphics and code for my project so that the compiling time has a really better performance. I just found a problem, tough.

One of the SWCs is a 'text container'. It is just a set of graphics with a dynamic text field in it. When I import the SWC from Flash CS5.5 apps, it behaves normally. I mean:

```
var swcInstance:SwcClass = new SwcClass
swcInstance.textFiel.text = "hello world!"
addChild(swcInstance)
```

and the swcInstance object is shown on screen with the text in it. When I do the same on FlashDevelop, tough, it appears on screen but text is not shown. Is this a known bug? Am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
I'm using Impact font with a drop shadow filter. Also, I made another test and Static text fields work properly.

EDIT 2:
The same problem happens partially with Arial. Some letters don't show up but others do. When I embed "All", it works fine with Arial. But even when I embed "All" with Impact it refuses to work, anything shows up.

Answer (score 3):

Set the `embedAsCFF` parameter to `false`

> Unless the SWF file was compiled with CFF, you must set the value of
>   the embedAsCFF property to false for the imported font.

Read more about that here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6320a-7fec.html

And here: 
http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=6456

Comment: where can I access such property so that I can change it?

Comment: where can I access such property so that I can change it?

Comment: In the @font-face declaration or the [Embed] tag.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like you may have these fonts included in other SWCs - if these SWCs are included first by the compiler the font they contain may hide other SWCs' fonts.

You could try un-adding all SWCs of your project, then adding them back starting with those with complete fonts.

PS: don't "embed all" chars of a font, choose the appropriate charsets - typically "Basic Latin" (US) and "Latin 1" (accented characters).